# Get monthly array with start date and end date of month in php

Tags: php, arrays, date

We already created Weekly array

Like

[1] => Array
           (
               [start] => 2017-01-01
               [end] => 2017-01-07
           )

But we need monthly array start date and end date of month

Just Like this

```
Array
   (
       [1] => Array
           (
               [start] => 2017-01-01
               [end] => 2017-02-01
           )

       [2] => Array
           (
               [start] => 2017-02-01
               [end] => 2017-03-01
           )

       [3] => Array
           (
               [start] => 2017-03-01
               [end] => 2017-04-01
           )

       [4] => Array
           (
               [start] => 2017-04-01
               [end] => 2017-05-01
           )

       [5] => Array
           (
               [start] => 2017-05-01
               [end] => 2017-06-01
           )

   )
```

Comment: Post your code.. let's see what you have tried..

Comment: If you already did the array for weeks, why would you have problem with months?

Comment: There is 7 days are fix in a week but month days are not fix each time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we are using [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) for achieving  expected output.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/848365)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$startDate="2017-01-01";
$endDate="2017-06-01";

$dates=array();
while($startDate!=$endDate)
{
    $monthEndDate=new DateTime($startDate);
    $monthEndDate->add(new DateInterval("P1M"));//adding one month each time we iterate
    $dates[]=array("start" => $startDate,
                   "end" => $monthEndDate->format("Y-m-d"));
    $startDate=$monthEndDate->format("Y-m-d");//changing start date
}
print_r($dates);
```